# Changes according to new Lightning Platform, have an effect on Admin 201 Exam?

Tags: certification, lightning-experience, admin

I am studying for the admin certification on Salesforce. I saw that the developer exam has had changes due to the new Lightning Experience. Does anyone know if the admin exam 201 has also changes?

Regards,
Silvia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no change in Salesforce Certified Advanced Administrator exam till today but if it will happen in future you can track it on 
[Salesforce Certified Administrator](http://certification.salesforce.com/administrators) page.